# Minimal polynomial of $I_n+aI(i,j)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider $E(i,j)=I_n+\alpha I_{(i,j)}$, where $I_n$ is the identity matrix of order $n$,  $I_{(i,j)}$ is the matrix with 1 on the $(i,j)$ position and 0 in other case ($i\neq j$), and $\alpha\in\mathbb{K}$ with $\mathbb{K}$ a field, $\alpha\neq 0$. Calculate the minimal polynomial of $E(i,j)$.

---

I have tried to approach this question for the entire day but I couldn't find a way to "attack" this problem, so any hint would be really useful. Also I have tried to look for it in the forum but I haven't found something useful, if the question is duplicated let me know.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Suppose that $\alpha$ lies along the diagonal. You should be able to find two different diagonal operators in terms of $E$, such that their product is zero. On the other hand, if $\alpha$ lies off the diagonal, can you see that $E - 1$ is nilpotent?

Comment: Do you mean 

$I(i,j)=\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 1 & . .  . & 1 \\
1 & 0 & . .  . & 1 \\
. & . & . . . & .\\
. & . & . . . & .\\
. & . & . . . & .\\
1 & 1 &  . .  . & 0 
\end{pmatrix}_{(n \times n)}$ ?

Comment: @nmasanta No! For example, if $(i,j)=(2,3)$ you'll have a matrix with 1 in $(2,3)$ entry and 0 in every other place.

Comment: @Edonbrayn Now it is clear to me.

Comment: The nearly standard notation for your $I(i,j)$ is $E_{ij}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll make use of the following two theorems:

> Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix with entries in a field $\mathbb{K}$ whose characteristic polynomial splits. Let $\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_k$ be all the distinct eigenvalues of $A$. Then,
>
> 1. The minimal polynomial divides the characteristic polynomial, and has the same roots as the characteristic polynomial. Which, in particular means there exist positive integers $p_1, \dots, p_k$ such that the minimal polynomial has the form
>      \begin{equation}
>    \mu_A(t) = \prod_{i=1}^k (t- \lambda_i)^{p_i}
>    \end{equation}
> 2. If $A$ is diagonalizable, then in the statement above, all the $p_i$'s are $1$. (the converse is also true but we won't need it)

The first statement can be proven with the Cayley Hamilton Theorem, and isn't too difficult. The second one is a fairly standard result so you can easily google it. Now, onto the proof of your question.

**Case $1$:** $i = j$.

In this case, $E_{(i,j)}$ is a diagonal matrix with eigenvalues $1+ \alpha$ and $1$. Hence, by the statement ($2$) above, the minimal polynomial is
\begin{equation}
\mu(t) = \left(t- 1- \alpha \right)(t-1)
\end{equation}

**Case $2$:** $i \neq j$.

In this case, $E_{(i,j)}$ is a triangular matrix (upper/lower depends on $i,j$), with $1$'s on the diagonal. So, its characteristic polynomial is $(t-1)^n$. So, by statement ($1$) above, the minimal polynomial of $E_{(i,j)}$ is of the form
\begin{equation}
\mu(t) = (t-1)^p,
\end{equation}
for some positive integer $p$. Clearly, $p \neq 1$, because otherwise it would imply $E_{(i,j)} = I_n$, which implies $\alpha = 0$; a contradiction. Next, you can verify for yourself that

\begin{align}
(E_{(i,j)} - I_n)^2 = \alpha^2 (I_{(i,j)})^2 = 0.
\end{align}
This, shows $p=2$.